# What is the meaning of opening and closing boundaries with regard to operators such as Buffer?

Tags: system.reactive

I do not understand the overloads of the Buffer operator that require an opening or closing boundary. The overloads I am refering to are:

```
public static IObservable<IList<TSource>> Buffer<TSource, 
TBufferClosing>(this IObservable<TSource> source, 
Func<IObservable<TBufferClosing>> bufferClosingSelector)

public static IObservable<IList<TSource>> Buffer<TSource, 
TBufferBoundary>(this IObservable<TSource> source, 
IObservable<TBufferBoundary> bufferBoundaries)

public static IObservable<IList<TSource>> Buffer<TSource, 
TBufferOpening, TBufferClosing>(this IObservable<TSource> source, 
IObservable<TBufferOpening> bufferOpenings, Func<TBufferOpening, 
IObservable<TBufferClosing>> bufferClosingSelector)
```

Could you please explain what the meaning of these boundaries is with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent to the `Window` operators (but each window yields `IList<T>` instead of `IObservable<T>`) that are documented here - http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html

I would suggest pausing and reading some of the doco that is currently out there on Rx. It is a small domain, but with lots of little concepts. The composition of these is the key to understanding it. Reading all of IntroToRx for example should take a few hours(it is only 17 pages).

Comment: Thank you. I went through the documentation for each of the operators and am familiar with the `Window` operator as well and had your book bookmarked in my browser to read but I confess, I haven't read it serially in full, and I probably should. Many thanks.